# Symfony twig - Third party

Tags: php, symfony, view, twig, overriding

i am currently working on a symfony project,

what i have:

```
app/Resources/views/mytemplate/
```

the folder mytemplate contains all of the important twig-views for my web app.

My question is, is there any possibility that third party members can create their own templates which override my "mytemplate" without creating controllers pointing to them ?

Like:

i have this template:

```
app/Resources/views/mytemplate/home/index.html.twig
```

An other person could create a new template in the same views directory like:

```
app/Resources/views/thirdparty/home/index.html.twig
```

to override my template.

is there any possibilty like this?

Greetings!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to me, you have two possibilities :

- The template that you want to be able to be redefined is the one specified with the method *renderView()* or similar in your controller : in this case, the possibilities are limitless. It's up to you to define the logic layer determining which template has to be rendered. You could for example force the user redefining the template to name it with a specific additional pattern, and then parse the right template to use thanks to a method inherited in all your controllers.

  ```
  $content = $this->renderView(
      $this->getInheritedTemplate('AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:index.html.twig'),
      array('name' => $name)
  );
  ```
- The template that has to be redefined is one inherited in another twig template : In this case, it's almost the same. You could imagine writing your own Twig filter/function in order to retrieve the right template. The code should be very similar to the first case.

Hope this helped.